# Xcode application submission fail

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

I have a problem when I try to validate my iPad application with Xcode:

- clean
- build for archiving
- archive
- clic on the validate button in the organizer
- choose the app and the distribution provisioning and clic "next".

And then it tells me "Packaging operation failed", nothing else.

What I checked:

- the build configuration for archive is distribution
- I tried to change the build config from distribution to release
- the provisioning for ditribution is the good one
- the bundle version is the same as on iTunes Connect
- I don't have folders in folders in my project folder
- I also tried to delete the ._ files with the cmd  "find . -name '._*.*' -exec rm -f '{}' \;" in my project directory

What can I do to pass the validation?

Comment: did you finally fix it? It would be great to know how.

Comment: It appeared that the problem was a .bundle I imported from a NAS in which there were some ._ files. I copyied the bundle in my project and all those ._ files disapperead  so I succeed submit my app.

Answer (score 1):

I had all these symptoms.  Finally after 6 hours i have passed "validation". I had previously moved my project between multiple computers and network attched storage devices / NFS systems, and did find several spurious "._*" files which i deleted.  One additional symptom: in the simulator i did not have a "home button".

Examination with "Pathfinder" from cocoatech i found many spurious files named "Icon" (just four letters) that were almost 300K in size with permissions 777 were in must directories and subdirectories for no reason. I deleted these. I also found one inside Settings.bundle, and deleted it. for some reason there was no group execute permission on that directory, so i modified it to be like other directories.

Lastly i found an extra "zh-Hans.lproj" file -- this app is English and internationalized four seven languages total, but this app, for learning Chinese characters, does not have a Chinese version (all my other apps do.) So i deleted the zh-hans.lproj file (again from the file system), did a new clean, build for archive, archive and was able to pass validation. (I could find no item in my project in Xcode that had a Chinese simplified internationalization).

At no time did ANY errors show up in any log file.  Just "packaging operation failed".

If anyone knows where these failures are logged, let us know.

Only after successful Validation does Xcode organizer show app size of 50MB; up until then it showed a trivial number (187K bytes?) that also indicated something fishy.

thanks for all the hints from folks chasing this down. Note that at no time were these Icon files visible from the terminal with any command I know. they were marked hidden. One of them (for settings.bundle) did show up in Xcode, but i could not select or delete it.

app submitted!

Answer (score 0):

The build configuration for archive must be RELEASE (not sure that's the problem)

Comment: In my others projects I always set it to distribution and it works, but I also tried to change it to release for this project but I always have the error

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html) an excellent tutorial by Reetu Raj about creating a distribution build.

Comment: I followed the tutorial in case I missed something but it doesn't work, I always have  the "packaging operation failed" error.